# Man of note got TE Lawrence in one (7)

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

> Man of note got TE Lawrence in one (7)

I guessed the solution from the cross clues and have, what I believe, is the correct answer. Please provide an explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE, take our [tour]! Please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259) for your question; in this case, it would simply be where you got the clue from. (e.g. if in a newspaper, the name of the paper and the issue date) Also, if you believe that you know what the answer is, it would be helpful to [edit] the question to include the expected solution. You may optionally use [spoiler formatting](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) if you wish to hide the answer from easy view.

Comment: This clue is in the public domain, having been used in various crosswords over the years. [Here](https://issuu.com/ashguardian/docs/ag-15_september_2017) I've found it in a NZ newspaper, the Ashburton Guardian.

Answer (score 14):

The answer I suppose you have is:

> **ROSSINI**

Explanation:

> The definition is 'man of note' - [Gioachino Rossini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gioachino_Rossini) was a famous Italian composer, a man of *musical* notes, so this is a cryptic definition for someone with a connection to music.
>
>  The wordplay is ROSS + IN + I, because 'John Hume **Ross**' was a pseudonym of [T E Lawrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._E._Lawrence), 'in' is literally IN, and I is the Roman numeral for the number one.
>
>  So overall, we have:
>
>  [Man of note] = TE Lawrence (ROSS) in (IN) one (I)

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer.